# connecting biztalk to sql server on virtual pc

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, virtual-machine

I have biztalk server installed on my host(physical machine) and i need to connect or use the sql server on my virtual pc 2007 machine.i have been running the virtual pc in loopback adapter networking mode but when i try to configure biztalk on the host machine it is not able to connect to the sql server on the virtual pc. it says
the database server you specified cannot be reached.any suggestions...

Comment: Can you connect to the SQL Server using SSMS from your host machine? You probably haven't configured the OS or DB security settings properly in the virtual pc.

Comment: hi i do not have sql server management studio on my host machine...and  i have enabled tcp protocol in sql config and also the allow remote connections clause..

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to change the networking mode on the virtual machine. In VirtualBox you can configure port forwarding for this. There may be something similar in Virtual PC.